# Python fixed future timestamp in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where I store username and future timestamp. The problem is that the future timestamp is not fixed and keeps shifting to the future every time the function run. Thus I'm not able to compare the current time with a stored timestamp.

Is there a way to store fixed future timestamp in the dictionary and keep them unchanged while the whole program is running?

For example:

```
users = {}

def recordUser(username):
   
    futureT = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
    if username not in users:
        users[username] = futureT

currentT = datetime.now()

if username in users:
     if users[username] > currentT:
         print("User is blocked")

recordUser(username)
print("Current time:", currentT)
print("Blocked until:", users[username])
```

The output I get is the future time constantly updating to the current time + 10 sec, which is understandable since I add 10 seconds to the current time. But is there a way to store future time in a dictionary as a fixed value, which is current time plus 10 sec?

Assume the time when the future time for the user recorded in the dictionary: `2021-04-16 07:43:00.465934`.

If we run it again at `2021-04-16 07:44:28.465934`, the output is:

```
Current time: 2021-04-16 07:44:28.465934
Blocked until: 2021-04-16 07:44:38.465647
```

Expected output would be:

```
Current time: 2021-04-16 07:44:28.465934
Blocked until: 2021-04-16 07:43:00.465934
```

**Edit:**

The file is the server and continuously running, while the client joins the connection. In my understanding, the time stamp should be kept unchanged in the dictionary as long as server.py is running.

Comment: Do you have any other sort of place where you're storing user information, such as a database or maybe memcache? Obviously each time you're running this file, everything will reset.

Comment: @user3832673 I updated the question: The file is the server and continuously running, while the client joins the connection. In my understanding, the time stamp should be kept unchanged in the dictionary as long as server.py is running.

Comment: Are you using something like Flask-Session to try to do this? Also, is your client native to your server's rendering functionality (something like a "render_template"), or are you calling this API from a different entity, for example a React client? Because the latter will not carry this sort of information over, and you'll have to find another way to store this sort of session data.